# Cake PHP 2 turn off default console output from shell commands

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I've written a custom shell in Cake PHP 2 under the `Console/cake my_shell` command, and have added my own `$this->out()` messages in places. Each time I run my shell, I get the default cake output first such as the path, and a welcome message. I'd like to disable these specifically for my shell but can't seem to find a setting to do so.

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.10.18 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /Users/user/Sites/project/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why are you still using CakePHP 2 in the first place? It has been out of support since a long time, and the now deprecated [Shell](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/shells.html) class has been replaced by [Command](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands.html) in later versions.

Comment: Not relevant to the question asked. The project is an old project and cannot be upgraded.